# Use a Fate Point for perform something without dice roll

Tags: fate, fate-core, fate-points

What is your opinion about let the PC to use a FP to perform a special action, difficult action consistent with his aspects, but without a specific stunt?

I think I recall some rule about that but I haven’t found anywhere.

The question is broad. Below, there's the specific example from my game session:

1. A jedi PC (“Wise jedi running away from empire”) sees 3 troopers at the end of the street: one zone away
2. Between jedi and troopers there is much crowd, and they do not see him yet
3. He wants, as an action, to perform a high jump, land between them and attack
4. Move between zones, jumping the crowd is not a simple movement, its an action

In this scenario, “You can spend a FP to jump over crowd as a jedi movement, and use your action to attack”, can be a good choice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like what you're describing is more like a Stunt. Those allow your character to do things normally too hard to "just do" because they're just that good. Some are powered by spending a Fate point, and they generally resolve without having to roll (or by giving you a bonus to a different, related roll).

Effectively, if you're allowing a player to make this move without rolling by spending a Fate point, you're giving them a free Stunt at least for that encounter. (This might not be a bad thing, depending on your group)

If your player is interested in playing a Jedi capable of making these kinds of fancy moves and is willing to pay properly for it, writing down a Stunt that allows it would be the normal Fate way of doing it.

There's a lot of example Stunts on the [Fate wiki](http://evilhat.wikidot.com/fate-core-stunts) to draw inspiration from. It even has something that's fairly similar to what you're looking for, or could be adapted to better fit your Jedi:

> **By My Hand, Set the World in Motion.** Through a combination of speed, dexterity, and uncanny timing, you always have a path forward. In a static environment, this means that you are capable of crazy parkour-like movement to get almost anywhere that could be physically accessed. In a more fluid environment you are impossible to pin down or fence in, as you’ll always find the gap. (Fate System Toolkit, p.95)

Answer (score 1):

### I force them to make it a narrative detail instead.

One of the standard uses of a fate point is to [add a story detail.](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/fate-point-economy)

> Declare a Story Detail: To add something to the narrative based on one of your aspects, spend a fate point.

So, I would rather than letting them auto succeed at the action, make them declare an interesting detail that would let them auto succeed.

For example, based on their "My family died in Alderan" aspect there's a festival ongoing honouring the Death Star protecting itself when Alderan fired first, and there's a giant inflatable death star they can jump on.

This makes for a more interesting story, and makes an aspect that both sides can tap on during the fight. If they want to boost a roll, they can just roll and use the fate point for a plus two. There's no need to change the rules for them.

Answer (score -1):

### Fate points are not to avoid rolling for your action

This is on page 12 of the rules:

> You can spend fate points to invoke an aspect, to declare a story detail, or to activate certain powerful stunts

There is one more, preventing a complication (p. 71). They all are listed again on p. 80, too. Buying a free action is not one of them, so you cannot just use a fate point to do that. The way this would normally be done is for you to establish a stunt that would allow you something like it, and spend the fate point to power that stunt.